# iOS Swift: Array of Objects conforming to a Protocol: How to check if array contains

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to implement an image downloader class. It's a singleton implementation. The idea is to ask the instance to download an image and register as an observer for that image download. This is what I came up with so far:

```
public protocol ImageDownloaderDelegate {
    func imageDownloadFinished(success: Bool)
}

public class ImageDownloader {
    var list: [Int64] = []
    var observer: [Int64:[ImageDownloaderDelegate]] = [:]
    var downloading: Bool = false

    public func downloadImageWithId(immutableId: Int64, delegate: ImageDownloaderDelegate) {
        // Add Id to download list
        if (!contains(list, immutableId)) {
            list.append(immutableId)
        }

        // Add Observer
        var observerList = observer[immutableId]
        if (observerList == nil) {
            observerList = [delegate]
        } else if (!contains(observerList, delegate)) {
            observerList!.append(delegate)
        }
        observer[immutableId] = observerList

        // Start to download
        if (!downloading) {
            self.downloadNextImage()
        }
    }

    private func downloadNextImage() {
        ...
    }

    /// A shared instance of the class
    public class var defaultImageDownloader: ImageDownloader {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = ImageDownloader()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

'ImageDownloaderDelegate' is not convertible to 'S.Generator.Element -> L'

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: if (!contains(observerList, delegate))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the correct arguments to the `contains` function, which expects a collection and a predicate (closure).

You need to do

```
public protocol ImageDownloaderDelegate : class {
    func imageDownloadFinished(success: Bool)
}

public class ImageDownloader {
    var list: [Int64] = []
    var observer: [Int64:[ImageDownloaderDelegate]] = [:]
    var downloading: Bool = false

    public func downloadImageWithId(immutableId: Int64, delegate: ImageDownloaderDelegate) {
        // Add Id to download list
        if (!contains(list, immutableId)) {
            list.append(immutableId)
        }

        // Add Observer
        var observerList = observer[immutableId]
        if (observerList == nil) {
            observerList = [delegate]
        } else if !contains(observerList!, { observer in observer === delegate }) {
            observerList!.append(delegate)
        }
        observer[immutableId] = observerList

        // Start to download
        if (!downloading) {
            self.downloadNextImage()
        }
    }

    private func downloadNextImage() {
        ...
    }

    /// A shared instance of the class
    public class var defaultImageDownloader: ImageDownloader {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = ImageDownloader()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't 'observer in observer === delegate' compare arrays of type [ImageDownloaderDelegate] with objects conforming to ImageDownloaderDelegate?

Comment: no, this is comparing two objects conforming to ImageDownloaderDelegate. You should look at the documentation for `contains` and read into how closures work as well.